# Retreive WCF query parameters as a single string

Tags: wcf, url, query-string, uritemplate

I need to define a WCF GET method which can retrieve all the query parameters as a single string. Example:

https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/token?client_id=abc_def&client_name=&type=auth&code=xyz

I want to grab the string "client_id=abc_def&client_name=&type=auth&code=xyz".

How do I define the URI template for the method? I tried the following, but it doesn't work as I will get 400 Bad Request. Replacing the /" with "?" makes no difference.

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "token/{Params}")]
[OperationContract]
Stream GetToken(string Params);
```

The method will call an external service and just forward whatever query parameters that it receives. I don't want individually retrieve each parameters, as it is possible that the parameters may increase.

Another URL would be like this:

https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/person/123456?client_id=abc_def&client_name=&type=auth&code=xyz

In this case, I would like to grab the two strings "123456" and "client_id=abc_def&client_name=&type=auth&code=xyz".

How do I define the URI template for the method?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the expected query string parameters in `UriTemplate`, like this:

`(UriTemplate = "token/{Params}&client_id={clientId}&client_name={clientName}&type={type}&code={code})`

And the method can be declared like this:

```
Stream GetToken(string Params, string clientId, string clienteName, string type, string code);
```

Comment: Hi, I already know how to do that. But that is not what I want. I want to get the whole query parameters as a single string. As explained in my post, my service will call another external service, passing on the query parameters. I don't want to parse each query parameter. If I am able to retrieve as a single string, there would be no need to change the code if there is change in the query parameters in the future.

Comment: It looks obvious but, have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString`?

Comment: No. Firstly, how do I specify the URI template for the method?

Answer (score 0):

You could omit the URI template and use the `NameValueCollection` from
`WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters`
Then just make a 'ToString()' call and you will get what you want

```
String fullQueryParams = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters.ToString()
```

If you need the path as well, for example to retrieve the `person` and `123456` strings in the url:

https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/person/123456?client_id=abc_def&client_name=&type=auth&code=xyz

you could use `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RelativePathSegments`. Then your OperationContract implementation will be something like this:

```
String fullQueryParams = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters.ToString();
//fullQueryParams = "client_id=abc_def&client_name=&type=auth&code=xyz"

var pathsCollection = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RelativePathSegments;
//pathsCollection = ["person","12345"]
```